# Getting NodeJS installed with Swift

Tags: node.js, swift, macos, shell

I want my application to install some website building tools vía nodes package manager (npm).
But my problem is that the user needs to have node already installed on his mac.

I thought about some kind of Shell script that is proving if node and npm are installed and if not downloads and installs those for the user.

You have any ideas how I could realize that?

The function I found:

```
func execute(command: String, args: [String]) -> String {

let task = NSTask()

task.launchPath = command
task.arguments = args

let pipe = NSPipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()

let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output: String? = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

task.waitUntilExit()

return output ?? ""
```

}

Comment: Use NSTask to launch scripts and apps.

Comment: @EricD thanks for your response! I found a function here on stack that does this NSTask thing. For a half week i have been using this function for displaying me the answer to the 'which node' cmd, to detect if node is installed. But now this seems no longer to work i have no idea why. When i type the 'which' cmd in the terminal its fine. You or anybody else has an more efficient way to see weather node is installed or not?